# Can I run phpspec tests (that use the network) without running a apache server

Tags: php, phpspec

Beginner question here but is it possible to run a PHPSpec test suite that contains tests that make REST calls without actually running a server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by mocking the service that makes the calls **BUT** TDD/BDD (and so PHPSpec) are not meant to be used for those kind of test that are [integration tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing)

For those kind of test I would recommend to use something like Behat